# Play an essential role

Tags: sentence-construction

I came across this sentence:

> It is only when the faculty of smell is impaired for some reason that we begin to realise **the essential role the sense of smell plays** in our sense of well-being

If I am right It will mean the same as sentence below:

> we begin to realise that the sense of smell **plays an essential role** in our sense of well-being.

There is many examples of "plays an essential role" but apparently the first sentence slightly differs from them.

I want to know which structure was used in the first sentence.

Comment: You're right. The example sentence has a relative clause _(that) the sense of smell plays,_ with the antecedent _the essential role_ understood as the object of _plays_ under relative clause formation..

Comment: Almost right. The first one also suggests to me some realisation of what the role is, while the second doesn't. I don't know that it makes any practical difference here though.